# Display Barcode for each Item in view Codeigniter using zend barcode framework

Tags: barcode-printing

I have to develop software for shop. i have list of product having their price and barcode digits. I want to show each and every items in product list html page along with barcode to take a print of barcode on stickers.

I googled about the zend barcode rendering and i tested also and found result ok with one barcode but here is my mai problem arise that i want to generate multiple barcode in foreach loop on my view->page.

I am very new to codeigniter please help.

**My Controller 'Barcode.php'.**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Barcode extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('successful_logged_in')){
        //load library
        $this->load->library('zend');
        //load in folder Zend
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        $this->load->model('common_model');
    }
    else{
        redirect('login','refresh');        
    }
}

public function index(){
    //Generate 13 digit random number to render barcode
    $temp = rand(1111111111111,9999999999999);
    $this->set_barcode($temp);

    $table='item_master';
    $order_by='name ASC';
    $data['item_list']=$this->common_model->select_active_records($table,$order_by);
    $this->load->view('home/header');
    $this->load->view($this->router->fetch_class().'/records',$data);
    $this->load->view('home/footer');
}

public function set_barcode($code){
    //generate barcode
    Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());
}
```

**In my View 'records.php'.**

```
<tbody>';
$i=1;
if($item_list==false){
    echo '<tr class="text-danger"><td colspan="3"><strong<i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size:12pt;"></i> - No record found</td></tr>';
    }
    else{
        foreach ($item_list as $row){        
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$i++.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->price.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->barcode.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo'
</tbody>
```

But this shows me only one barcode on entire html body page which was generated by random number

**I Want the final result something like this** 
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZYnd.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a folder in your root directory like : root/barcode   

public function set_barcode($code){
        //generate barcode
        $file = Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());
        $code = time().'1222';
        imagepng($file,"barcode/{$code}.png");
        $data['barcode'] = $code.'.png';
        $this->load->view('dashboard/products',$data);
    }

// Add view page like this
       <img src="<?php echo base_url().'barcode/'.$barcode; ?>" alt="">
```